# Unable to click the checkbox via Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Why am I unable to click the following checkbox on the page https://realty.yandex.ru/add via Selenium in Python?

[image]

```
import traceback

import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.webdriver.support
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui


explicit_wait_timeout_secs = 10


def wait_for_element_presence(driver, find_type, web_element):
    return selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_wait_timeout_secs).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((find_type, web_element)))


def wait_for_element_clickable(driver, find_type, web_element):
    return selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_wait_timeout_secs).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((find_type, web_element)))


try:
    driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get('https://realty.yandex.ru/add/')

    # element = wait_for_element_clickable(driver, By.NAME, 'lift')  # TimeoutException
    element = wait_for_element_presence(driver, By.NAME, 'lift')  # WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (203, 899). Other element would receive the click: <span class="checkbox__box">...</span>
    element.click()
except Exception:
    print('ERROR: \n' + traceback.format_exc())

try:
    driver.quit()
except Exception:
    pass
```

If I'm trying to wait for the "clickability" of this element, it gives me `TimeoutException` error. If I'm trying to wait for the presence of the element, it gives me "element is not clickable" error.

However, I can click this checkbox via Javascript:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByName('lift')[0].click();")
```

Also it works in Firefox btw.

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using `Firefox` driver? it works on mine

Comment: @Anzel Yep, just tried it and it works

Comment: so it's not working on Chrome driver?

Comment: @Anzel Yep, you're right

Comment: There are multiple elements with the same name so that might be the reason what i believe, Instead of My name locator try using xpath locator with below value and see what happens.

//label[contains(text(),'Лифт')]

Comment: @FrozonHeart, the Timeout is likely raised by `until`, could you tried using just like `until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_name("blah blah")`?

Comment: @Rupesh Shinde Yep, it works. However, I don't see any other elements with the "lift" name on this page. What is the reason of such behavior then?

Comment: @Anzel Could your rephrase please? What is the exact code that I should check?

Comment: on `def wait_for_element_presence(...)`, change to: `return selenium.webdriver.support.ui.WebDriverWait(driver, explicit_wait_timeout_secs).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_name(web_element))`

Comment: @Anzel Unfortunately, it gives me "element is not clickable" error too

Comment: @FrozenHeart, in that case I have a gut feeling that Chrome handles the **click** differently, as you see from "lift" css, it's index on **-1** which means Chrome is trying to click on the **<span>** rather than the actual checkbox "lift"

Comment: but hey, if @RupeshShinde comment works for you, perhaps xpath is just a good alternative :)

Comment: @Anzel What does this index mean? This index equals -1 in Firefox too btw

Comment: @FrozenHeart, I meant Firefox driver perhaps will trace the actual name "lift" to simulate the click, whereas Chrome remembers the pointer position and click on the element (which will be **<span>** on top). It's just my gut feeling though

Comment: @FrozenHeart : Please Check this link,, but still wondering about the relation of this to this issue https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3508

Answer (score 9):

You need to click on the `span` tag that is a parent of a parent of the `input` tag with `name="lift"`:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[span/input[@name="lift"]]')
element.click()
```

Works for me in both Chrome and Firefox:

[image]

To be safe, you can also [*scroll to an element*](http://www.anggrianto.com/blog/scroll-element-view-webdriver/) before clicking:

```
def scroll_element_into_view(driver, element):
    """Scroll element into view"""
    y = element.location['y']
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, {0})'.format(y))

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[span/input[@name="lift"]]')
scroll_element_into_view(driver, element)
element.click()
```

Comment: Do you know why? Shouldn't it work to click on the checkbox itself?

Comment: @rifaco well, this is a wonderful and mysterious world of browser automation and web-scraping - it really depends on how this particular web-page is implemented, cause there can be all sorts of techniques involved. Just trying to say that "shouldn't it work" is not a valid question - the only answer could be "it depends" :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

we can use this to click on an element using Javascript

```
element=driver.find_element(By.ID,"sdd")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

or

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", driver.find_element(By.ID,"sdd"))
```